# for loop in recursive function

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I am facing critical issue in recursive function. This is my recursive function:

```js
iterateJson(data, jsonData, returnedSelf) {
  var obj = {
    "name": data.groupName,
    "size": 4350,
    "type": data.groupType
  };

  if (data.parentGroupName == jsonData.name) {
    jsonData.children.push(obj);
  } else {
    if (jsonData.children) {
      for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.children.length; i++) {
        if (data.parentGroupName == jsonData.children[i].name) {
          jsonData.children[i].children.push(obj);
          elementFound = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (elementFound) {
        return jsonData;
      } else {
        if (jsonData.children) {
          for (i = 0; i < jsonData.children.length; i++) {
            if (elementFound) {
              return jsonData;
            } else {
              jsonData = jsonData.children[i];
              jsonData = returnedSelf.iterateJson(data, jsonData, returnedSelf);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }

  return jsonData;

},
```

Now the problem is that, in the second for loop, (jsonData.children.length)

my jsonData is getting changed. how to retain the parent jsonData .

Hope my question is clear.
Editing to make it more precise.
suppose initially jsondata has 5 elements and i enter the loop took first children as new jsonData and call this function again. so when the condition will get fulfilled, it should return to for loop and jsonData should have that initial element of 5 data. rather than that, it is having new json data which is first  child element of original jsonData.

My ask is how to retain that parent jsonData with 5 element.

Comment: Objects are passed by reference so `jsonData = jsonData.children[i];` will cause issue. try `jsonData.children[i] = returnedSelf.iterateJson(data, jsonData, returnedSelf);`

Comment: You can declare a globa variable outside your function that get the value jsonData.children.length

Comment: `children` is a live collection meaning that it updates it's length automatically. So if you use a recursive loop that relies on the length remaining the same on every iteration while it's being compared to `i`, length may be increasing as you push more into the array. If this is happening, then you might want to use array methods like forEach or map. I haven't looked seriously yet so...

Comment: @Rajesh It didn't work. Instead it gave me Converting circular structure to JSON error. because i am using JSON.stringify on the returned result. Please read my edited question for more clarity.

Comment: @zer00ne His `children` property has nothing to do with [`ParentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children).

Answer (score 0):

As I Do not know about input data but

```
jsonData = jsonData.children[i];
jsonData = returnedSelf.iterateJson(data, jsonData,      returnedSelf);
```

This are only lines who can override jsonData.